# Using iconv to convert utf8 format resulting in an error

Tags: r

I have tried many things from a few posts from Stackflow but with no success.

There are a bunch of English and French names in database so to avoid something like this

```
Current output:
Ga�tan 
Expected output:
Gaétan
```

The code that i am currently using

```
rs = dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * from dim_survey_response_alignment")
rs$`advsr_nm` <- iconv(rs$`advsr_nm`,from = "UTF-8")

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, advsr_nm, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 357
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Try `rs$advsr_nm <- stringi::stri_trans_general(rs$advsr_nm)` from `stringi` package!

Comment: it says argument "id" is missing, with no default

Comment: Thanks for guiding, researched a bit more on the error and got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer it by writing the following:

```
rs = dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * from dim_survey_response_alignment")

Encoding(rs$advsr_nm) <- 'utf-8'
```